# Realm Swift - Find by IDs

Tags: swift, realm

I need to query Realm objects using a list of ids, id being the object's primary key. I have tried the following:

```swift
// Query a list of Dogs by their _ids
let doggoIds = ["1", "2", "3", "1", "2"]
realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("_id IN %@", doggoIds)
// Result: [Dog1, Dog2, Dog3]
```

The list of ids contains duplicates, but as you can see the result is a list of unique Dog objects.

I'm wondering if anyone can think of a different way to write this query so that we get a nice `Results<Dog>` collection from that list of ids that includes duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want duplicates? Keep in mind that Results only contains unique objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Realm.objects().filter` returns a list of "live", managed objects. It will not return duplicates because there is only one object matching the primary key. In order to accomplish what you want, you'll need to <s>create an 'unmanaged' duplicate of each object and make your own array of those unmanaged objects</s> map each returned instance into your own array.

A la:

```
let doggoIds = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
    for managedMuttId in doggoIds {
        if let managedMutt = realm.object(ofType: Dog.self, forPrimaryKey: managedMuttId) {
            // unmanaged.append(Dog(value: managedMutt))
            duplicateList.append(managedMutt)
        }
    }
```

Comment: @EmilienHuet This is a good answer but the text isn't correct. Swift Arrays can hold duplicate objects so there's no reason to create unmanaged versions for the Realm objects since they will be stored in an array.

Comment: I can see now how the OP asked for a `Results<Dog>` type result, so this doesn't answer his question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The reason I wanted a `Results<Dog>` collection is so I can take advantage of Realm collection notifications, and filter/sort the collection in my `NSTableView`. Hopefully using an array with those things won't have too much of a performance impact.

Answer (score 5):

Realm results contain unique objects so the easiest solution is to query for each dog and add the result to an array. CompactMap does this well as it filters out nil.

```
let listOfDogsToFind = ["Fido", "Dino", "Sport", "Fido", "Cupid"]

let dogArray = listOfDogsToFind.compactMap { dogName -> DogClass? in
    if let result = realm.objects(DogClass.self).filter("dog_name == %@", dogName).first {
        return result
    }
    return nil
}

for dog in dogArray {
    print("dog name: \(dog.dog_name)")
}
```

assume Cupid doesn't exist, here's the output

```
dog name: Fido
dog name: Dino
dog name: Sport
dog name: Fido
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jay, `compactMap` is a great suggestion, however since I'm searching by ID and not by name, `object(ofType:, forPrimaryKey:)` is probably more appropriate here.

Comment: @EmilienHuet This was a design pattern - you can use dog_name, ID, shoe_size or whatever field is applicable.